# decimal.Parse wont work in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, parsing

First of, I hope I´m not stepping on any toes by posting the same question again. Yesterday I posted a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734071/trouble-when-using-parse) that was put on hold because I was beeing unclear i think.

Now i´ve been doing some noob-research and the .Parse problem only seems to occur when i use decimal.Parse. For example, this works fine:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = "500";
            int num = int.Parse(text);
            MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
        }
```

But this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            decimal text = decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            decimal total = text * 2;
            MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());

        }
```

Results in this error: 
(The value in textBox1 is 10.00)
[image]

I have tried reinstalling Visual studio but the problem persists.

EDIT:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
       at System.Decimal.Parse(String s)
       at WindowsFormsApplication4.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\Form1.cs:line 23
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication4.Program.Main() in c:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What is your locale setting? `(Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);`

Comment: What value is in the `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: The problem is probably in using wrong decimal separator. Like `,` instead of `.`.

Comment: @Steve, I dont know where to see/change that. What should I look for?
Also, the same exercises that doesnt work now used to work before. Im talking about exercises from at c# book, where I know the source-code is correct.

Steve, I opened a new CosoleApplication in VS and copied your code but it gets underlined in red..Not the right way?

Comment: @user2915962 It is very likely a culture issue, as culture affects parsing because of formatting of things like numbers and dates. Both Steve and Ondrej are pointing in this direction. You can control parsing by overriding the culture formatting, but it is usually best to try and accommodate culture-specific variances.

Comment: The question is what language your operating system is set to. The Parse Methods will behave differently in different language settings. If the value in your textbox is 10.00 try using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek, You are right! Allthough its the other way around..When I changed . (rightway) to , (wrong-way) it displayed 20!

Comment: Could you add the exception details to the above question? (click 'Copy Exception Details to the Clipboard' and edit the above question)

Comment: @Steve It's just a `FormatException`, the `DateTime` part could just be the troublshooter list trying to be clever and failing. I never use that thing anyway.

Comment: So have I, by mistake, changed some culture formatting so that now I need to use , instead of . ? If so, can i change it back?

Comment: @Steve This is really weird. I added using System.Globalization; at the top. Changed the value in textBox1 from 10,00 back to 10.00. The messageBox displayed 20,00...

Comment: Going back to the first comment. What is your locale?

Comment: Can I check my locale from within VS? Maybe with the code you added in your first comment?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are actually passing in a string containing a number I believe that it is failing to a culture issue. Here are some tips:

- Specify a `NumberStyles` in a different overload of the `Parse` method
- Specify an Invariant culture in a different overload of the `Parse` method
- Specify both

See example below:

```
decimal text = decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And a tip not directly related to your question...always use the `TryParse` to make the conversion safer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but im afraid the answer is a bit over my head..I tried to replace the my first line with the one you wrote bur i get an error:  numberstyles dont exist in this context..

Comment: @user2915962 Add `using System.Globalization;` on the top of the file with the other `using` directives.

Comment: Did you reference the `System.Globalization` namespace? That's the only reason why you should get this error which is actually a compilation error

Comment: This is really weird. I added using System.Globalization; at the top. Changed the value in textBox1 from 10,00 back to 10.00. The messageBox displayed 20,00...But why is this? I must have changed a setting somewhere and I would really like to get back to "normal" again.

Comment: @Leo While I agree that locale is probably the issue, I'm curious which locale would make it fail like this. For example, I live in NL and we use comma as decimal separator, yet `decimal.Parse("10.00")` would not fail, it would parse to `1000` (which is kind of scary actually).

Comment: I live in Sweden and we use comma to,  isnt there maybe a setting somewhere that lets me change it back?

Comment: Did you check the international settings of your PC?

Comment: @user2915962 Ah, Sweden. Very interesting. Don't you allow use of periods as a digit grouping symbol? For example 10.000,00? As for changing the behavior I recommend using explicit culture settings like in this answer.

Comment: You need to target a specific culture and/or style if you don't need the default behavior. The code example in my answer is a template, a guide showing the potential of the `Parse` method. If you need to target a specific culture the use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` and for the `NumberStyles` there is already and MSDN documentation explaining the different types of styles you can use which is quite extensive  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve Is it the region-setting? Language for non-unicode programs?
Its set to swedish, but as far as i know it always was..

Comment: @Thorarin
Thank you. When asked about "my locale", do you refer to the region settinsg Current system Locale in windows? If so, that is now set to swedish. Should i change this?

Comment: @user2915962 No, you shouldn't change this. You should decide whether your software wants to use the user's locale (in which case the original implementation was okay, minus some decent error handling in case of invalid input) or whether you want to used a fixed locale inside your software, in which case you can set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` or explicitly provide CultureInfo explicitly in every call where it matters.

Comment: @Thorarin Tahnk you so much for your help but I dont understand what to do. I would like to decide that my software goes back to the original implementation where I could use . (periods)instead of ,(commas)  .  I guess that I must have changed something i the last couple of days beacuse last week i was decimal.parsing with periods like there whre no tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

`decimal.Parse`  expects you to provide valid numeral string i.e. "0.5", "1" and similar.
If you try to pass an invalid string i.e. " ", "sdf", then it will throw exception.

I suggest you to use `decimal.TryParse`. TryParse, returns boolen to indicate successful conversion, and sets an `out` variable.

Also, you should consider passing the `CultureInfo` in one of the overloads, as in not all cultures , is treated as decimal point, hence

```
 CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");//pass your culture
 decimal result;
 decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Any, info, out parsedValue))
```

Comment: This answer is actually devoid of anything useful. The OP appears to be providing a valid string and `TryParse` will attempt the same type of conversion as `Parse`, just with exception consumption. This initially leads us down the culture formatting route.

Comment: hey @AdamHouldsworth, OP is directly parsing textbox.Text, hence is highly prone to feed invalid string, he should, therefore, must check for its validity, so it seems to be useful, just like when u suggest sql injection when somebody tries to execute a query from c#

Comment: `TryParse` is one way of handling it, but it isn't necessarily the correct way, and it won't necessarily handle this problem which appears to be understanding and catering for culture-specific formatting. `TryParse` is useful, but it is no different than manually handling exceptions and doesn't at the moment directly relate to the details in this question.